# WAR file won't start on Tomcat 7

Tags: spring-mvc, war, tomcat7, tomcat

I have a WAR file that I have deployed to Tomcat 7.0.23 via the web manager. When I try to start it though, I get the error below. Not sure what could be causing this. I'm using JDK 1.6.0_27. I'm also using the latest version of Spring MVC for the application I'm trying to run on Tomcat and I'm on Windows 7 64-bit.

```
Dec 21, 2011 10:41:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Dec 21, 2011 10:41:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/upload] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Edit: Ok, so I setup logj4 and set it to DEBUG and it told me that an exception was being thrown on the characterEncodingFilter. Below is code in my web.xml for the characterEncodingFilter.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Edit: Here's the top part of the new error I see logged:

```
2011-12-21 12:43:56,279 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/upload]- Exception starting filter characterEncodingFilter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.<init>(GenericFilterBean.java:82)
```

[Full log](http://pastebin.com/J9EkYEsq)

Comment: Anything in the logs? Have you cranked up logging to DEBUG for the duration? Obviously from the information you've provided it will be impossible to help. My first suspects would be config file errors or missing dependencies.

Comment: you can check what happens when the code mapped to `/upload` starts up. BTW, does it work when you deploy it manually.. just to remove Tomcat Manager out of equation.

Comment: Well, a `Filter` failed to start. It threw an exception when Tomcat attempted to load/construct/initialize it. That's all which can be said based on the information provided so far. The real answer is in the stacktrace of the exception which was been thrown. Check the Tomcat log files.

Comment: This is all that's in the Catalina.log: [http://pastebin.com/PEWKdWz9](http://pastebin.com/PEWKdWz9)

Comment: I setup log4j and and set it to DEBUG and here is what I got: [http://pastebin.com/J9EkYEsq](http://pastebin.com/J9EkYEsq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that you're missing Apache Commons Logging on your classpath. Is it being bundled in the war file?

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have fixed the not starting problem but now for whatever reason I'm getting a 404 error.